# Keep popover alive in SVG

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I'm trying to add a popover element inside of a svg `text` element. In order for the popover to display in SVG land, the `container` has to be set to `body`. In order to keep the popover alive in Bootstrap land, the `container` has to be set to the element with the popover attached.

I have also tried adding a `foreignObject` above the `<text>` element with a `<div>` to hold the popover, but the `foreignObject` fails to display.

I'm working with bootstrap `3.3.2`.

```
<g>
    <text class="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-content="hello world"></text>
</g>
```

```
$('.popover').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover focus',
    placement: 'auto',
    container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: Please add a working code snippet.

Comment: The code pasted above is working in that the popover appears on hover.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]. so we can see for ourselves what is happening.